# I am trying to retrieve the details (first Name, last name, gender etc) of friend of face book using facebook id

Tags: java, android, json, facebook

My Code is:-

```
try
    {
        params.putString("fields", "first_name");
        params.putString("fields", "last_name");
        params.putString("fields", "link");
        params.putString("fields", "gender");
        params.putString("fields", "birthday");

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(facebook.request(Id, params));
        JSONArray array =   json.getJSONArray("data");
        if(array != null)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++)
            {
                String name = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
                String birthday = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("friends_birthday");
                String location = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("friends_location");
                String web = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("friends_website");

                System.out.println(name+"-"+birthday+"-"+location+"-"+web);
            }
        }

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
```

where do I am commtting mistake. please help me. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Your mistake? Actually: not telling us, what happens with when you run your code ;)

Comment: better delete your last comment ASAP! The link contains some data you shouldn't give away. Better add the (sanitized) result from the get to your question

Comment: I could not be able to retrieve the required attributes, However these even not give any error
but also not print results in terminal

Comment: try priniting the array length may be it may be 0 so that it may not be entering into the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is very hard to help you without you telling us what you are trying to do with your code and what is going wrong with it.

However, by looking at your code, I would tell you to confirm that you are putting the fields you want in the correct way. If params works like an hashtable, you would be overritting the values for key "fields" - so instead of asking for first_name, last_name, etc you would be asking only for birthday.

Comment: I am trying to retrive First Name and last name and Birthday... but in terminal no result is showing except the url of desired result ID which contain the value

Comment: Is System.out.println ever being called? What is being printed?

Comment: nothing get printed in System.out.println

Comment: So your problem seems to be that "array" is either null or empty (check which is the case), which makes me think that the problem is in your query to facebook. What is the Id that you are passing in facebook.request(Id)? Also check the json object (maybe try to print it) - the data you want may not be under "data"

Answer (score 1):

we can get the details of a user's friends
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
        String accessToken = facebook.getAccessToken();

```
    try
    {
            params.putString("format", "json");
            params.putString("access_token", accessToken);

            String url = "https://graph.facebook.com/"+Id;
            String response = Util.openUrl(url, "GET", params);

            JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);
            String fname = json.getString("first_name");
            String lname = json.getString("last_name");
            String birthday = json.getString("birthday");
            String gender = json.getString("gender");
            String location = json.getString("locale");
            String web = json.getString("link");

}
catch(Exception e)
{

}
```